# Question from Katok and Hasselblat (page 195, Exercise 5.1.4)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, dynamical-systems

I've been stuck on this problem from Katok & Hasselblat for a while. I think it shouldn't be hard but I can't make progress.

**Question**. Suppose $M$ is a non-orientable manifold and $\pi:M^*\rightarrow M$ is an oriented double cover, and $I: M^* \rightarrow M^*$ is the corresponding involution. Prove that there exists a non-degenerate $n$-form such that $I^*\omega = -\omega$ and hence $\pi_*|\omega|$ is an odd $n$-form on $M$.

---

I think what they mean by the involution is the map

$$I\left(p, \pm\left[\left.\partial/\partial x^1\right|_p, ..., \left.\partial/\partial x^1\right|_p\right]\right) := \left(p, \mp\left[\left.\partial/\partial x^1\right|_p, ..., \left.\partial/\partial x^1\right|_p\right]\right)$$
where $x: U\rightarrow \mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$
is a chart about $p$ on $M$.

---

What I think is that since $M^*$ is orientable, one should be able to take a volume form $\Omega$ on $M^*$ and then define $\omega:= \Omega - I^*\Omega$. Obviously $I^*\Omega = - \Omega$. However, $\omega$ may fail to be non-degenerate. This would mean, for some $p \in M$ and some chart $x$ about it,
$$\omega_{\left(p, \left[\left.\partial/\partial x^1\right|_p, ..., \left.\partial/\partial x^1\right|_p\right]\right)} = \left(I^*w\right)_{\left(p, \left[\left.\partial/\partial x^1\right|_p, ..., \left.\partial/\partial x^1\right|_p\right]\right)}.$$

So far I wasn't able to rule this out. Indeed I suspect this might not work out.

Comment: Why are you writing $I_*$ rather than the usual pullback of differential forms? Since $I$ is an involution, I agree that it's not a big deal, but I would rather reserve the lower star for the trace construction you will do pushing forward by $\pi$.

Comment: Agreed. I think I wrote it this way in the beginning and then kept doing it the same way till now. I'll change it in a moment. The notation used in the book might also be a reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "However, $\Omega$ may be non-degenerate"?

Comment: Apologies. It was meant $\omega$. I'll fix that too.

Comment: You mean *not* non-degenerate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148329/discussion-between-master-aka-and-ted-shifrin).

Comment: My suggestion is that you think about why/how $M^*$ is orientable. Using local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ near $p$, how does $\Omega$ appear at the two points lying over $p$?

Comment: I see. I thought about it but couldn't prove orientability. I need to think on it more but I think this was a good enough hint. Once I know how to define a consistent orientation, it would be probably apparent what I need to do if the volume form does not already violate the equation that I don't want! Thanks a lot for your answer. I will reply later if I still had problem proving orientability.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi. I recognised what I was afraid of will never happen as the orientation at $(p, o_p)$ and $(p, -o_p)$ is always different after pushing forward on $M$. The equality that I was worried about is equivalent to saying that they pushforward of $\Omega$ at $p$ and $I(p)$ are the same under the projections. Also, I figured out why the oriented double cover is orientable. It's so natural to define a pointwise orientation on it. The formality and notation was what was making me so much confused.